# Electron WebView Back Button clearing form

Tags: webview, electron, browser-cache, back

I want to add back and forward navigation button to my browserWindow in my Electron App, but although with Firefox and chrome when we use the back navigation any form input are reloaded with cached data with Electron webview using goBack()function clear these everytime. Is there any setup, options or way of keeping the data ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear.

Electron [documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#contentsgoback) doesn't explicitly state whether Electron implements what is called BFCache or HistoryLists. 
It isn't clear from Electron source code either. I created relevant [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8504) on Github.

Electron uses Chromium to implement `BrowserWindow`. Situation with BFCache and Chromium itself isn't very clear. There are multiple issues that state
that BFCache isn't implemented in Chromium ([455226 Chrome reinitializes all fields to the value they had on their initial presentation when history back is used](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455226), [510340 Investigate faster back/forward page navigation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=511340)). Although I've seen in practice that BFCache works in Chrome.

You can save and restore form state using JavaScript, `sessionStorage` and window load and unload events. But in this case you also need a mechanism to clearly identify `input` nodes and store serialized files in case if form contains file inputs.

For more information check:

- [You Do Not Understand Browser History article](http://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history) by Matthew Beale
- [`Window.sessionStorage` MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
- [MDN page about BFCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching)

Comment: I thank you for your answer which strengthenmy opinion about that. I start to write my own code testing with localstorage but will use sessionstorage to clear when close the browser. Sure there are solution somewhere since Brave browser written with Electron got the same behavour that chrome for form state restored with back button... Anyway,after spending enough time I choose the workaround solution..